# Override toString() for Freemarker Java List<Map> variable

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, freemarker

I would like to create a Java Freemarker variable that works in a template both as

```
${myListOfMapsVar}     <#-- calls toString() on myListOfMapsVar -->
```

and

```
<#list myListOfMapsVar as item>
  ${item.mapKeyName}
</#list>
```

It seems like this should be possible using something like

```
List<Map> myListOfMaps = ...
var myListOfMapsVar = new MyWrappedObject();
myListOfMapsVar.wrap( myListOfMaps );
```

```
class MyWrappedObject extends DefaultObjectWrapper {
  MyWrappedObject() { super(); }

  public String toString() {
    return "a string representation of my list";
  }
}
```

However, when I try this, the ${myListOfMapsVar} works as expected, but the list enumeration produces an error:

> The value you try to list is an extended_hash+string (.... wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel), thus you must specify two loop variables after the "as"; one for the key, and another for the value, like <#... as k, v>).

What am I doing wrong?

btw, I cannot change any application-wide Freemarker configuration.

Comment: You are mixing up the `ObjectWrapper` and `TemplateModel` concepts. `MyWrappedObject` is just a generic object to FreeMarker, as it doesn't implement any `TemplateModel` interfaces, nor is it an instance of a well-know class (like `String`, `Map`, etc.). Such an object is an FTL string, and an FTL "hash" (basically a `Map` with string keys) that contains the Java Bean properties and Java Bean actions of the class. Hence the confusing error message.

Comment: @ddekany Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible? (Having a variable that's a list that can be iterated and also be used as a String with an overloaded toString()?). I tried using DefaultListAdapter.adapt() -- no luck. I also tried extending SimpleSequence -- no luck there either.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You just need an object that implements both `TemplateSequenceModel` and `TemplateScalarModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that come later, here's my solution

```
class MyListOfMap<K,V> implements TemplateSequenceModel, TemplateScalarModel {

    DefaultObjectWrapper wrapper = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_27).build();
    List<Map<K,V>> listOfMaps;
    Function<Map<K,V>,String> mapper;

    MyListOfMap( List list, Function<Map<K,V>,String> mapper ) {
      listOfMaps = list;
      this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString() throws TemplateModelException {
      var strings = listOfMaps.stream().map( mapper ).collect(Collectors.toList());
      return String.join( ", ", strings );
    }

    @Override
    public TemplateModel get(int index) throws TemplateModelException {
      return new MapModel( listOfMaps.get(index), wrapper );
    }

    @Override
    public int size() throws TemplateModelException {
      return listOfMaps.size();
    }
  }
```

```
var mylist = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
mylist.add( Map.of( "first", "John", "last", "Smith", "age", "32", "city", "Chicago", "State", "IL" ) );
mylist.add( Map.of( "first", "Jane", "last", "Doe", "age", "29", "city", "Memphis", "State", "TN" ) );
mylist.add( Map.of( "first", "Mark", "last", "Roy", "age", "38", "city", "Boston", "State", "MA" ) );
    
var listOfPeople = new MyListOfMap<String,String>( mylist, 
        (person) -> person.get("first") + " " + person.get("last"));
    
var dataModel.put( "people", listOfPeople );
```

Variable 'people' can be used as a 'summary' string *and* as a list of hashes

myftltemplate.ftl:

```
${people}  <#-- evaluates to: John Smith, Jane Doe, Mark Roy -->
```

and can also be used like

```
<#list people as person>
  <tr>
    <td>${person.first}</td>
    <td>${person.last}</td>
    <td>${person.age}</td>
    <td>${person.city}</td>
    <td>${person.state}</td>
  </tr>
</#list>
```

Thanks to @ddekany for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have been helpful. Without it, I'm going to make a guess.

From the [Manual](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html):

```
... to list the key-value pairs of a hash (since 2.3.25):

<#list hash as key, value>
    Part repeated for each key-value pair
</#list>
```

So the error message

```
you must specify two loop variables after the "as"; one for the key, and another for the value, like <#... as k, v>)
```

is telling you that you need to add a second variable, and probably rename `item` to something like `key`, as in

```
<#list myListOfMapsVar as key, value>
  ${key}
</#list>
```

Just curious: Do the key objects in your map have a method named `mapKeyName`?

Finally, your data is in the form of `List<Map<?,?>>`. If this is really the case, my sense is that your Freemarker template should read:

```
<#list myListOfMapsVar as myMap>
    <#list myMap as key, value>
        ${key}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

Comment: I understand the error message. I just doesn't make sense (to me) in this context. If I don't wrap the List<Map> in the DefaultObjectWrapper, the #list enumeration works just fine. My reason for using the wrapper was so that it ${myListOfMapsVar} would also resolve as a String. My problem is that I can't get both requirements to work concurrently.  Another commenter pointed out that DefaultObjectWrapper is not the way to go, so I'll explore more in that area.